# How to Force On Load Browser Full Screen

Tags: javascript

I need to make a webpage open in a browser without any borders, scrolls, menus or bars. 
This script appears to do it onClick.
I wish to have the page open full screen onLoad instead. I have modified the script but no luck.

By the way I don't need the cancelFull screen. I just posted it in case someone wants to use it.

Can someone help, please?

Here is the original code with the click.

```js
(function () {
    var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("view-fullscreen");
    if (viewFullScreen) {
        viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var docElm = document.documentElement;
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
                docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
        }, false);
    }

    var cancelFullScreen = document.getElementById("cancel-fullscreen");
    if (cancelFullScreen) {
        cancelFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            }
            else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
            else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            }
            else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            }
        }, false);
    }


    var fullscreenState = document.getElementById("fullscreen-state");
    if (fullscreenState) {
        document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
            fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreenElement)? "" : "not ";
        }, false);
        
        document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function () {
            fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.msFullscreenElement)? "" : "not ";
        }, false);
        
        document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
            fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.mozFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
        }, false);
        
        document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
            fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
        }, false);
    }

    var marioVideo = document.getElementById("mario-video")
        videoFullscreen = document.getElementById("video-fullscreen");

    if (marioVideo && videoFullscreen) {
        videoFullscreen.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            if (marioVideo.requestFullscreen) {
                marioVideo.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (marioVideo.msRequestFullscreen) {
                marioVideo.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (marioVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                marioVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                /*
                    *Kept here for reference: keyboard support in full screen
                    * marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                */
            }
        }, false);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

For now, the answer is that you cannot do this in at least Chrome, which probably makes it a non starter. Chrome requires that `webkitRequestFullscreen` be called during a user interaction event (click, mouseup, etc). Otherwise you'll get:

`Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

Answer (score -3):

I believe most ~90% browsers will support:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

});
```

Or if you are using jquery, call the same function you call on click in

```
$( document ).ready()
```